# PHP - separate character by spaces and remove everithing before and afrer

Tags: php, split

I have a little issue and I don't know how to call it :D 
So I want to (simply) remove everything before and after character separated by space. For example:

Input: `"Hello holy world"`
Key: `"ho"` or `"hol"` etc.
Output: `"holy"`

or

Input: `"testing text"`
Key: `"tex"`
Output: `"text"`

Comment: use preg_match(); (regular expression in php.

Comment: look it the other way around, you want to search a string, and find the whole word that matches your search string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your not removing so much as searching and displaying the match.

```
$search ='ho';
$str='Hello holy world';


preg_match("/\w*$search\w*/", $str,$out);

print_r($out);

Array
(
    [0] => holy
)
```

`\w*` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

demo:https://regex101.com/r/iX3nF6/22 lets you experiment with other strings\options

Comment: @KubaxusKolek you should learn to accept answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers